# Is it possible to use the new Checkout to only collect payment info

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to follow Stripe's guide "[Starting a subscription with Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions/starting)"

I have two plans setup on Stripe - a free and a paid one.

I want a free user to be able to submit payment information before upgrading to the paid plan.

Is this possible to accomplish with Checkout? When I'm trying to create a session ID for Checkout, I'm getting the following error from Stripe:

> Stripe::InvalidRequestError ((Status 400) (Request req_NfaWVXSezbnkId) Checkout does not support plans with the value 0 for `amount`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done via Checkout's "setup mode".

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/collecting

> Collecting payment details using Checkout’s setup mode is useful for updating a subscription payment method or for setting up a payment method on file for future payments. Setup mode uses the Setup Intents API to create Payment Methods.